# Displaying Special Case Of Sorted Firebase Arrays (with AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So basically I have a set of clubs, and a set of users.  Each club and each user has a specific latitude and longitude.  Showing all clubs to a user is easy with ng-repeat, but I'm trying to just show clubs within a certain distance of each user.  So what I've come up with so far:

```
var arr = [];
$scope.clubs.$loaded().then(function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.clubs, function(value, key) {
       if($scope.getDistance(value.lng, value.lat) == true) {
        console.log(value.name + " it's close enough!");
         arr.push( {id: value.$id, description: value.description, name: value.name});
       }
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
$scope.narr = arr;
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?  I'm basically singling out data from a firebase array, and then putting it into a smaller array (arr) and then ng-repeating through it.  But now it's not a firebase array...  Any ideas?


p.s. I don't think I can use any of the built in firebase sorting, because distance is unique for each user, and each location requires a latitude and longitude.

Comment: Doh, I can just ng-repeat through the arr array by adding arr to scope, so no worries there.  Still hoping there might be a little more elegant way to solve this though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i went with GeoFire. It's pretty much the same implementation as above, but should be much better for scaling.  If anyone is interested, this is what your GeoFire function would look like:

```
var array = [];
$scope.publicArray = array;
$scope.geoFunc = function() {
    geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [userData.Latitude, userData.Longitude],
    radius: 25
  });
      geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
    console.log(key + " is located at [" + location + "] which is within the query (" +    distance.toFixed(2) + " km from center)");
    var newRef = new Firebase(furl + "/clubs/" + key);
    $scope.thing = $firebaseObject(newRef);
    array.push($scope.thing);
  });
};
```

And then you could just ng-repeat through your publicArray.

Answer (score 0):

Why not evaluate `$scope.getDistance()` in your template?

You'll only need to create a `$firebaseArray()` on `$scope`.

```
$scope.cabyns = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

Then in your template you can call `$scope.getDistance()` with the item in `ng-repeat`. Using an `ng-if` direction, you can state whether it should be loaded.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in cabyns"> 
    <span ng-if="getDistance(item)">
      {{ item.name }}
    <span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another thing you could try doing is using [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire) if you're doing geofencing.

Comment: That $scope.cabyns was a typo, that is a firebase array of clubs (changed above).  So it's waiting for the $firebasyArray to load, then running the distance check against the firebase array.  So I think your solution is the same amount of processing, because it's still checking the getDistance on each item, no?

Comment: Reading up on GeoFire, looks like it might be helpful :)